# HIbernate + JPA OneToMany Lazy loading not working if no foreign key specified in the db

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, nhibernate-mapping

Hibernate lazy loading is not working in my code. It loads the entire data even it is specified as FetchType LAZY

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    public OrderItem getItem(String itemId) throws Exception {
        OrderItem item = itemDao.find(OrderItem.class, Integer.parseInt(itemId));
        if (item == null) {
            throw new Exception(502, "We are unable to load item for #" + itemId);
        }
        return item;
    }

    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_order_detail")
    @Fetch(value= FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<OrderItemStateChangeEntry> itemStateHistory;
```

I could not able to lazy load the contents. There is no foreign key constraint set in the db. And its not possible to set as the many parent data not present in the system.

Can somebody help me on this

**Update**
Added  my class and reference. But lazy load work

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ps_orders")
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="id",column=@Column(name="id_order")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="createTime",column=@Column(name="date_add")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="updateTime",column=@Column(name="date_upd"))
})
public class Order extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "id_carrier")
    private Integer carrier = 0;

    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy="order")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<OrderStateChangeEntry> orderHistory;

    //Getters and Setters
}




@Entity
@Table(name = "ps_order_history")
@EnableBouncerProfile
public class OrderStateChangeEntry implements java.io.Serializable{

    public OrderStateChangeEntry(){}

    public OrderStateChangeEntry(Order order){
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_order_history")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_order", nullable=false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Order order;

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

Comment: The problem was due to the Jackson Serialization module that I used. I now used the Hibernate Module 4 and now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of your

```
@Fetch(value= FetchMode.JOIN)
```

it disables the lazy loading ...

As you specify the fetch mode in your @OnetoMany relationship, i would say that you can simply remove that line above.

Comment: I have tried even without @Fetch(value= FetchMode.JOIN) and it didnt work.

Comment: this is not about foreign key in DB ... can you post more ? your entire entity maybe ... and have a look at that link, and delete that @Fetch http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/

Comment: Got the problem, it was due to the Jackson serialization. I was able to fix the issue now using Hibernate4 Module.